# Twitter Bootstrap: Select element in Nav bar

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am having issues with `<select>` elements lining up in a bootstrap nav bar. I want the text from "Search for" all the way to the "Go!" button to be vertically aligned. It looks as if the button and selection elements are the same height, so I want them to be flush on the top and bottom.

Here's the code:

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="brand" href="#">Project</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-search pull-right">
                <div>Search for 
                    <select class="span2">
                        <option>Things</option>
                    </select> in 
                    <select class="span2">
                        <option>City, NY</option>
                    </select>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Go!</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a jsFiddle with an example. http://jsfiddle.net/jefe317/EjS6f/2/

Both Firefox and Chrome show similar results

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rohit's answer kind of works but can leave the text off center a little. You can also remove the margin-bottom from the select:

```
select[class*="span"] {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

That should even everything out.

http://jsfiddle.net/EjS6f/5/

Answer (score 0):

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EjS6f/4/)***

Hi **@Jeff Lange** Now define  your **button** `margin-top:0;` and **add to** `vertical-align:top;`

As like this

```
.btn.btn-primary{
margin-top:0 !important;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EjS6f/4/)***

Comment: That does align the elements properly, but there is a little extra padding at the bottom of the bar, still. Combined with @DavidF 's edit, this works perfectly, though! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but I fixed it with:

```
<select class="span2 navbar-btn">
    <option>Things</option>
</select> in 
 <select class="span2 navbar-btn">
   <option>City, NY</option>
</select>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Go!<button>
```